# Trigonometric equation lose of solution

Tags: calculus

I tried to solved this equation, but I missing some solution why?

$\sin(3x)-\cos(3x)=1$
$3x=t$

$\sin(t)-\cos(t)=1$

$\cos(t)=\sin(90-t)$
then:

$2\sin(\frac{t-(90-t)}{2})\cos(\frac{t+90-9}{2})=1$

$2\sin(t+45)\cos(45)=1$ then:

$\sqrt{2}\sin(t+45)=1$

$\sin(t+45)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

$t+45=45+360K$
or $t+45=135+360K$

then I pluged in $t=3x$ 
$3x+45=45+360K$
so:
$x=120K$

or 
$3x+45=135+360K$
so:
$x=30+120K$

but the results should be $60+120K$ or $30+120K$ and it seems like I missing $60+120K$ where I'm wrong? could I replace $3x=t$ without lose results ?

thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$2\sin\left(\frac{t-(90-t)}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{t+(90-t)}{2}\right) = 2\sin(t\color{red}{-}45)\cos(45).$$

Comment: Thanks , I missed it !

Answer (score 1):

I would use that
$$\sin(x)-\cos(y)=-2 \sin \left(-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}+\frac{\pi }{4}\right) \sin
   \left(-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2}+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, for these kind of equations we can use by $t=\tan \frac {3x} 2$ with $\frac {3x} 2 \neq\frac{\pi}2+k\pi$

- $\sin (3x) =\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$
- $\cos (3x) =\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$

and therefore

$$\sin(3x)-\cos(3x)=1 \iff \frac{2t}{1+t^2}-\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}=1 \iff2t-1+t^2=1+t^2 \iff t=1$$

that is

$$\tan \frac {3x} 2=1 \iff \frac {3x} 2=\frac{\pi}4+k\pi \iff x=\frac{\pi}6+\frac{2k\pi}3 $$

now we need to check directly on the original equation the case $$\frac {3x} 2 =\frac{\pi}2+k\pi \implies 3x =\pi + 2k\pi \implies x=\frac{\pi}3+\frac{2k\pi}3$$

which satisfy the equation and therefore it is a valid solution.